# I have two variables that I know are equal but my if statement does not recognise this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

This is my code:

```
bookings = ['blue,red', 'green,orange', 'yellow, purple']
number = 0
b = 0
c = 1

file_test = open('test_1.txt' , 'wt')

results_song = []

for item in bookings:
   words = bookings[number].split(',')
   results_song.append(words[0])
   results_song.append(words[1])

   number = number + 1

results_song_str = '\n'.join(results_song)
print(results_song_str)

file_test.write(results_song_str)

file_test.close()

file_test = open('test_1.txt' , 'r')

line = file_test.readlines()


for item in bookings:

    line_1 = line[b]
    line_2 = line[c]
    answer = input('If first word is then what is the second word')

    if answer == line_2:
       print('correct')
    else:
       print('wrong')

    b = b + 2
    c = c + 2
```

However the code will not recognise that answer is equal to `line_2`. I cannot figure out why this is happening. I have checked that `c` is the correct number and that `line_2` is the same as answer. But I did notice that when I ran the code while printing answer and `line_2` that this would return:

```
red

red
```

but I never put a new line feature in here.

Any help would be much appreciated as I need to use this code for a school assignment.

Comment: before your if statement, `print(repr(answer), repr(line_2))`, I suspect there is some whitespace not taken into account

Comment: [Minor Issue] In your first for loop, you're not using `item`, it becomes redundant. Use it instead of `bookings[number]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging by printing

```
# ...

for item in bookings:
    line_1 = line[b]
    line_2 = line[c]

    print("Your Answer:", repr(answer))
    print("Actual Answer:", repr(line_2))

    # ...
```

gives

```
Your Answer: 'red'
Actual Answer: 'red\n'
```

Aha! A sneaky newline character! Seems like when the program was reading text from the file and splitting the lines, it saved the newline character for you. How sweetly annoying. : |

To remove it, you can use the `str.replace()` method

```
# ...

for _ in range(len(bookings)):   # I took the freedom to modify the loop conditions

    line_1 = line[b].replace('\n','')
    line_2 = line[c].replace('\n','')

    # ...
```

or change the way lines are read from the file, manually splitting the lines using the `str.split()` method

```
# ...

with open('test_1.txt' , 'r') as file_test:
    line = file_test.read().split('\n')

for _ in range(len(bookings)):
    line_1 = line[b]
    line_2 = line[c]

    # ...
```

---

*Credit goes to @juanpa.arrivillaga for suggesting the use of `repr()` to check values.*